# Profiles with environment url in Maven

Tags: maven, selenium

This is part of my pom.xml with two profiles which contain URL to different environments:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <properties>
        <environment>yyy</environment>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>uat</id>
    <properties>
        <environment>xxx</environment>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

also i have `evironment.properties` file in `src/main/java/resources` with body:

```
environment=${environment}
```

I run a program with mvn clean test -Ptest
Now how can I access to value from my maven profile?
I create reader class:

```
    package utils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Reader {

    public void readProperties() {

        Reader app = new Reader();
        Properties prop = app.loadPropertiesFile("src\\test\\resources\\properties\\environment.properties");
        prop.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));

    }

    public Properties loadPropertiesFile(String filePath) {

        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try (InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)) {
            prop.load(resourceAsStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to load properties file : " + filePath);
        }

        return prop;

    }
}
```

but if I run reader function in my test it gives me NullPointer at:

```
Reader objReader = new Reader();
objReader.readProperties();
```

How can I access my URL defined in profiles?

Comment: You probably need to configure the surefire plugin to give you the required properties as system properties.

Comment: You are calling `readProperties` which uses a directory which does not exist on the resource. The location must be `/environment.properties` cause during the build the resources `src/test/resources` will be copied to `target/test-classes/` which is the classpath for the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the following in You **pom.xml** :

Build section:

```
   <build>
        <resources>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${custom.resource}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

....

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>cloud</id>
        <properties>
            <custom.resource>devnew</custom.resource>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

...

**devnew**  config itself might look like :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbqww.png

```
baseUrl=abracadabra....
```

And Your prop loader will look:

```
public void environmentPropertiesLoader() throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "custom.resource";
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Property File '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
    }
    prop.load(inputStream);
    baseUrl = prop.getProperty("baseUrl");

    inputStream.close();

}
```

Your correct command with the profile will look:

`mvn clean test "-Pdevnew`"

Hope this do a trick for You.

Also recommend [the article describing how to set up maven project from scratch](https://experitest.com/blog-cat/testng_framework_maven/).

Best regards,
Eugene